# DesignerAttribute in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible in WPF to provide an alternate class which should be used as the control to show in the designer instead of the control itself, just like `DesignerAttribute` does for WinForms?

**EDIT:**
What I'm looking for is what happens with e.g. the [`ReportViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.aspx) class does. This class has an associated class `ReportViewerDesigner` which is used in the designer instead of the `ReportView` class itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the [Metadata Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546923%28v=VS.90%29.aspx); since WPF separates the designer metadata into a separate assembly as noted in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514704%28VS.90%29.aspx).

> In the System.ComponentModel
>   framework, a designer type is
>   associated with its corresponding
>   component through the
>   DesignerAttribute metadata attribute.
>   This means the relationship is
>   established at compile time, forcing a
>   hard-coded dependency between the
>   component's run-time and design-time
>   behavior. To attach a different
>   designer, you must change the
>   DesignerAttribute declaration and
>   recompile the component's code base.
>
> In the WPF Designer, designer metadata
>   is factored into a separate assembly,
>   physically decoupling it from the
>   run-time implementation. This freedom
>   means that different tools can present
>   completely different design
>   experiences for the same run-time
>   type. For more information, see
>   Metadata Store.

A concrete example of this is the VS designer versus the Expression Blend designer.

**EDIT:**

As noted in the comments section they are fundamentally different approaches. It is not a 1:1 by any means; just as is with a WinForms versus WPF approach to building an application. If you are looking for an elusive attribute which will simply use a differing class as the designer representation; it does not exist. There are certainly ways to achieve what you want and allow the designer to display a given control in a myriad of ways but the approach is not like that of WinForms.

- [How To: Use the Metadata Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514529%28v=VS.90%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MS.INTERNAL.METADATA.EXPOSEDTYPES.XAML.STATICEXTENSION%29;k%28VS.XAMLEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V3.5%22%29&rd=true)
- [WPF Designer Extensibility
  Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514646%28v=VS.90%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MS.INTERNAL.METADATA.EXPOSEDTYPES.XAML.STATICEXTENSION%29;k%28VS.XAMLEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V3.5%22%29&rd=true) (look at Designer Instance Creation)

Comment: I've read the above, but this wasn't was I was looking for. I have a WPF control which I cannot use to show in the designer. Instead, I need the ability to have an entirely different control shown in the designer like e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.aspx where `ReportViewer` has the class `ReportViewerDesigner` to show in Visual Studio instead of the control itself.

Comment: They are fundamentally different concepts; WPF versus Windows Forms. Check out the additional related examples and information in the updated answer...

Comment: I know. My situation is that I have a XAML based control library **not** based on WPF for which I need a visual designer. I was hoping I could provide WPF controls as the controls to show on the designer instead of having to create my own designer.

Comment: "XAML based control library not based on WPF"...is this an in-house product or 3rd party? If 3rd party; where is the library?

Comment: If this is a reusable control library created in XAML but not based on WPF; what is it based on? SL?

Comment: I have a system where I have forms running in an AppServer. These forms are serialized and remoted to a Windows GUI. In the Windows client, the object structure is deserialized and using WinForms, forms are created. I also have an AJAX (Ext JS) web client which does the same. When on the server a property is set, that set action is send to the client and the control on the client is updated and visa versa. So, on the server, there aren't actually controls in the WPF/WinForms sense. However, I still need to be able to design the forms. The XAML for these forms are the spitting image of WPF.

Comment: @Pieter Perhaps you could leverage the existing controls within WPF and derive from a base class which would allow you to then leverage the pre-defined styling for the given control; at least from a design stance. If they are vastly different then anything that currently exists with the WPF framework you could derive from Control and build out the style within Generic.xaml from the ground up to provide the styling element you desire. This would eliminate the need to deal with the Metadata Store in its entirety.

Comment: I though about that, but the problem is I cannot inherit from the WPF controls for my framework. I need my own base classes. This is the reason I was hoping for something like the `DesignerAttribute` because this would give me a chance to create a parallel control library based on WPF. It would be great if you'd have a suggestion how I could leverage WPF for the design phase and still have my own controls for runtime.

Comment: @Pieter If you are simply trying to use VS to design the form in XAML and get a visual response; why not use something like http://kaxaml.com/ instead?

Comment: Wouldn't that still require my controls to inherit from `ContentControl` etc?

Comment: Valid XAML syntax would be required. If it is not XAML then you need to build something from the ground up as mentioned earlier; as XAML is the underlying representation of the visuals within WPF/SL. It sounds like what you have is XML which resembles XAML...but that is about it?

Comment: No, it actually is XAML. In fact, I use the XAML designer in Visual Studio for this. It automatically generates code with event/control name hook-up and runtime I use the BAML optimized resources. It is XAML, just not WPF.

Comment: @Pieter I would give kaxml a try; I haven't used it in a couple of years and it may meet your needs...from a design stance.